# count not obeying where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

hello help please confused...

I have this query that suppose to pull out only the counts for the typei column, but when i run it, it pulls out the count for the entire database and doesnt obey the where clause rule...

```
SELECT [type], typei, vtdate, count (typei) as count
FROM vtindex
where typei is not null or typei <> '#'
and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30'
GROUP BY
[type], Typei, vtdate
HAVING
COUNT(typei) > 1
```

The idea is that the user puts in a date spam, and gives them the counts of typei for that specific date spam

thanks...

Comment: Without knowing what your data looks like (i.e. edit your question and include some sample data) and expected results (i.e. edit your question and add this also), it's unlikely that we can fix the query.

Comment: I think you have to drop the column `typei` out of your select-clause and select only `[type], vtdate, count(typei)`. And remove it from the group-by clause.

Comment: @damien_The_Unbeliever you dont need data for fix a query imho see below they have already started fixing the query and one of them is already right, but thanks for the input....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT [type], typei, count (typei) as count
FROM vtindex
where typei is not null or typei <> '#'
and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30'
GROUP BY
[type], Typei
HAVING
COUNT(typei) > 1
```

Idea is to remove other fields than Typei and group by it.

Good luck!

Comment: This is working just not excluding the '#' for some reason

Comment: I think, you should work with condition: try to put parenthesis here: where (typei is not null or typei <> '#') and ...

Answer (score 2):

In the GROUP BY - Clause there have to be only the columns you want to group by, not the ones you want to count or sum. So try it with:

```
SELECT [type], vtdate, count(typei) as count
FROM vtindex
WHERE typei IS NOT NULL OR typei <> '#'
   and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30'
GROUP BY [type], vtdate
HAVING count(typei) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parenthesis to filter the records properly.

Currently you where clause is validated in following order

```
Where typei IS NOT NULL OR (typei <> '#'
  and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30')
```

But you need this

```
Where (typei IS NOT NULL OR typei <> '#')
  and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30'
```

Comment: this helped sorry stupid me didn't think to bracket the where clause i normally do, ad this in part help me solve the problem so thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this;)

```
SELECT [type], typei, vtdate, count (typei) as count
FROM vtindex
where (typei is not null or typei <> '#')
and vtdate between '2016/06/01' and '2016/06/30'
GROUP BY
[type], Typei, vtdate
HAVING
COUNT(typei) > 1
```

Without this parentheses, when `typei` is not null, the other conditions will not be computed.

Comment: this will work for another report thanks, but also including the '#' for some reason